# Representing a for loop with modulus in formal notation

Tags: sequences-and-series, logic, notation

I have the following section of code I am writing for research. Basically I need to formally represent the mathematical notation behind a set that follows:

```
for (int i = 1; i < h; i++)
    if (h % i == 0)
        // i is part of the set
```

I am not very familiar with formal mathematical notation, and was wondering if anyone can help me express this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set could be specified like this: $S = \{i : (1 \leq i < h) \land (h ~\%~ i = 0)\}$.